# How to destructure obj[arr[0]] = arr[1]

Tags: javascript, eslint

Given the following code eslint throws a prefer-destructuring error at me:

```
const params = {};
const splitted = 'key=value'.split('=');
params[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
```

How can I use destructuring in the third line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Try the below example, it assign value at zero index to key variable and value at first index to value variable.

```js
const params = {};
const [key,value] = 'key=value'.split('=');
params[key] = value;
console.log(params);
```